# MySQL - ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect datetime value, on a Timestamp column

Tags: mysql, datetime, error-handling, timestamp

I have a MYSQL column that is defined as TIMESTAMP.

Whenever I create a row with javascript `new Date()` the value is stored ok without issues.

However when I want to update the value, sending the same `new Date()` on that column, i get an error

```
Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect datetime value: '2017-06-16T17:35:34.377Z' for column 'last_access'.
```

I can manage the whole thing as Datetime and format the date accordingly to solve the error, however I want to understand why the error is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The Date must be formatted like "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" for [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/date/).

If you want to insert a Date with JS, try to make your own string.

```
const newDate: Date = new Date();
const dd = newDate.getDate();
const number = newDate.getMonth() + 1; // month start at 0, we have to add 1.
const yyyy = newDate.getUTCFullYear();

const insertString = `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`;
```